# Variable after object, how does that work?

Tags: php, reference

I couldn't find any good answer on this, so I'm asking it. It's hard for me to believe that nobody asked this before. Okay, I noticed the following PHP-code that I couldn't understand:

```
$path = new Path('/a/b/c/d');
echo $path->cd('../x')->currentPath;
```

If I'm not mistaken, `$path` is the class Path here. And `cd` is the function. But I see that `currentPath` is also being called.

When I tried it out, I get a notice:

```
Trying to get property of non-object in line ##
```

So I'm trying to figure this out. If I am right, it's called the global variable `currentPath` which will be then defined in the `__construct`?

Comment: __construct may/may not affect currentpath, but that depends on exactly what's in the Path constructor.

Comment: Here is the code of the __construct of the class Path, that I could get with this: http://pastebin.com/qyt6m1HQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return $this.

```
class Path
{
    public $currentPath;

    function __construct($path)
    {
        $this->currentPath = $path;
    }   

    public function cd($newPath)
    {
        $this->currentPath = $newPath;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right one, then I get the results and he didn't warned about properties of non-object. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you provided in http://pastebin.com/qyt6m1HQ the `cd` method doesn't do anything at all except throw an exception. However if it were to `return $this` your code would work and yes it would be accessing the public `$currentPath` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it didn't worked out for me.. In the `cd` method, I defined  `$this->currentPath = getcwd();` and `return $this->currentPath;`. But I still get the same notice?